# table or column not found in mysql join with selects and cases

Tags: mysql

So I have this bit of mysql that I'm trying to work out. My goal is to insert the count of a grouping into the primary records to tell me how many of each status is within the related table for the record, so the result might look like this:

```
| id | name      | count1 | count2 |
------------------------------------
| 1  | primary 1 | 5      |  3     |
| 1  | primary 2 | 2      |  7     |
```

---

```
select * from primaryTable
left join (
select 
    case 
    when relationTable.relation_status_id = 1
    then count(*)
    END as count1,
    case 
    when relationTable.relation_status_id = 2
    then count(*)
    END as count2
) relationTable
on relationTable.primary_id = primaryTable.id
```

I tried using a subquery to do it, which worked, but requires a select per count, which I'm trying to avoid.

Adding a group by to the subquery resulted in an error that more than one row was being returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the subquery, rather than aggregate `COUNT()`s inside `CASE`, you may more easily use `SUM()` to add up the result of a boolean comparison (`0` or `1`) to return a result resembling a count.

```
SELECT 
  primaryTable.*,
  count1,
  count2
FROM
  primaryTable
  JOIN (
    SELECT 
      primary_id,
      -- Sum the results of a boolean comparison
      SUM(relation_status_id = 1) AS count1,
      SUM(relation_status_id = 2) AS count2
    FROM relationTable
    -- Group in the subquery
    GROUP BY primary_id
  -- Join the subquery to the main table by primary_id
  ) counts ON primaryTable.primary_id = counts.primary_id
```

Note that because MySQL treats the booleans the same as 0 or 1, the comparison `relation_status_id = 1` returns 1 or 0. The syntax above isn't supported in every RDBMS. To be more portable, you would need to use a `CASE` inside `SUM()` to explicitly return an integer 1 or 0.

```
SUM(CASE WHEN relation_status_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count1,
SUM(CASE WHEN relation_status_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count2
```

Your original attempt has some syntax problems. Chiefly, it has no `FROM` clause, which is causing MySQL to think it should be treated as a scalar value and then complain that it returns more than one row.